# php array common key sum array of array

Tags: php

I want key rating sum common slug key value. Please help me out.

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 6
                        [slug] => scenario
                        [avis_id] => 2
                        [rating] => 0
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 7
                        [slug] => jeu_d_acteur
                        [avis_id] => 2
                        [rating] => 9
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 8
                        [slug] => effets_speciaux
                        [avis_id] => 2
                        [rating] => 0
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 9
                        [slug] => prises_de_vues
                        [avis_id] => 2
                        [rating] => 0
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 10
                        [slug] => bande_son
                        [avis_id] => 2
                        [rating] => 6.8
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [slug] => scenario
                        [avis_id] => 1
                        [rating] => 8
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [slug] => jeu_d_acteur
                        [avis_id] => 1
                        [rating] => 5
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [slug] => effets_speciaux
                        [avis_id] => 1
                        [rating] => 5
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4
                        [slug] => prises_de_vues
                        [avis_id] => 1
                        [rating] => 6
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 5
                        [slug] => bande_son
                        [avis_id] => 1
                        [rating] => 8
                    )

            )

    )
```

output:

```
    Array
                            (
                                [slug] => scenario
                                [rating] => 8
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [slug] => jeu_d_acteur
                                [rating] => 14
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [slug] => effets_speciaux
                                [rating] => 3
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [slug] => prises_de_vues
                                [rating] => 6
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [slug] => bande_son
                                [rating] => 14.8
                            )

                    )
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please, use `var_export()` instead of `var_dump()` when you show arrays in SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge them by using `...` splat operator and loop through to group by `slug` and sum `rating`

```
$merged  = array_merge(...$a);
$r = [];
foreach($merged as $v){
 isset($r[$v['slug']])
 ? ($r[$v['slug']]['rating'] += $v['rating'] ) 
 : ($r[$v['slug']] = ['slug'=>$v['slug'],'rating'=>$v['rating']]);
}
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/odCl6